# silverlightPage.g.cs , What is "g" for?

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I recently started working on SilverLight and WPF.

I am just curious why microsoft choose "*.g.cs" name for the partial code-behind class. Is there any significance of the letter "g" here?

It is very much like the designer.cs of asp.net world. The only difference i know about is the "InitializedComponent()" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "g" stands for "generated", as these are auto-generated.

Comment: but don't you sometimes think they missed a golden opportunity by not using "ag" for auto-generated?

Comment: I cringed myself - both when I thought of it and actually wrote it. I even waited the 30 seconds to get to post another comment. I'm a lost cause.